# Make Navigation Bar Fixed When Scrolling in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar

In my application I added a navigation bar to a scrollable view. But when I scroll the view, the navigation bar scrolls with it. How can I make the navigation bar fixed when scrolling? Thanks.

Comment: Don't add the navigation bar to the scroll view if you don't want it to scroll. Why not put the view controller with the scroll view in a navigation controller?

Comment: @rmaddy thx, I will try it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your "StoryBoard". Click on the document outline then select your view controller. Select the objects you want to scroll and go to "Editor" -> "Embed In" -> select "Scroll View". It will add all the objects selected to scroll view. Create outlet for the scroll view and add the required scroll view code.